# Deleting duplicate geometry in PostGIS tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, osm2pgsql, duplication

After - I don't know what happened - all my entries in my PostGIS tables are doubled. I tried this to delete them but it does not delete any/all duplicates:

```sql
DELETE FROM planet_osm_point
       WHERE osm_id NOT IN (SELECT min(osm_id)
                        FROM planet_osm_point
                        GROUP BY osm_id)
```

or this:

```sql
DELETE FROM planet_osm_point
WHERE osm_id NOT IN (
    select max(dup.osm_id)
    from planet_osm_point as dup
    group by way);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the current `planet_osm_point` table structure? means type of columns. You can write a basic Python code to collect the selected columns, if having difficulty with the SQL functions.

Comment: Yes, that will work, if you have another id (ctid) that is not duplicated. I was assuming that everything was identical and duplicated twice.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get this `ctid` approach. This column has been added manually after the duplication event?

Comment: "The column ‘ctid’ is a special column available for every tables but not visible unless specifically mentioned. The ctid column value is considered unique for every rows in a table. - "http://technobytz.com/most-useful-postgresql-commands.html

Answer (score 26):

One way of doing this, is to use a window function and partition by geometry, so that each repeated geometry gets an id: 1, 2, 3, etc (or 1, 2) in your case, and then you just select from the table where the `id = 1`, to get a unique set of values (attributes and geometry) back, e.g.,

```sql
WITH unique_geoms (id, geom) AS (
    SELECT
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ST_AsBinary(geom)) AS id,
        geom
    FROM some_table
    )

SELECT
    geom
FROM
    unique_geoms 
WHERE
    id=1;
```

Obviously, you would need to add the other osm columns in the select too, this is just for illustration, but this is basically like grouping by geometry and just selecting the first instance of each one. Note, you need to use **`ST_AsBinary()`** in the **Partition By** as otherwise the comparison is done on the bounding box, not the actual geometry.

As all the other attributes are presumably the same for each geometry pair, you would so something like this for all the other fields, including osm_id, and to actually create a new, unique table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE osm_unique AS
    WITH unique_geoms (id, osm_id, attr1, attr2,... attrn, geom) AS (
        SELECT
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ST_AsBinary(geom)) AS id,
            osm_id, attr1, attr2,... attrn, geom
        FROM
            osm_planet_point
        )
SELECT
    osm_id, attr1, attr2,... attrn, geom 
FROM
    unique_geoms 
WHERE
    id=1;
```

This might be quicker than deleting from an existing table, especially if there are lots of indexes in place.

Rewritten for readability, but, leaving the credit to [@dbaston](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/18189/dbaston) for drawing my attention to `ST_AsBinary(geom)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have made a note. But for example let's consider this scenario where there is a point geom which is both a bus stop and a crossing (don't consider the OSM data). Then we will have two identical geom representing these two features. Using your approach will remove one of the feature. What I am saying is that how to solve this problem when there is no specific column to `Partition By`?

Comment: Hi Zia, then you partition by (geom, attribute), so that they both have to be the same in order to get the same id. In your example, the geom would be the same, the attribute not, so row_number() would return 1 for both.

Comment: This currently identifies distinct geometries with a shared bounding box as duplicates (since `PARTITION BY` uses the `=` operator, which works on bounding-box equality).  I'd suggest changing the above to `PARTITION BY ST_AsBinary(geom)` as a fix.

Comment: I think you should accept this answer, or state how it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AndreSilva. Done. I am always nervous about changing answers without making it clear there has been an edit. But, you are right, this is much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

A more general answer to easily delete geometry duplicates in PostGIS table. The following command deletes all features with duplicate geometry in "table_name" based on primary key (column "gid") and equality of geometry (column "geom"). Be aware it really deletes all geometry duplicates, they will be gone, forever! Maybe back up first?

```
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name a
    USING schema_name.table_name b 
WHERE a.gid > b.gid AND st_equals(a.geom, b.geom);
```

Please be aware the solution using [st_equals](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html) is to remove all spatially equal duplicates. This might be especially helpful in cases where you did comparison by binary but still have 'duplicate' geometries - typically reversed/different vertices order. Depending on particular case this might or might not be desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method I used to remove duplicates from a SSURGO soil data download. The downloaded shapefiles did not have a unique key, so a serial pk column was generated when I imported to PostGIS. There were a few overlaps in the data sets, and I inadvertently imported some records more than once while developing the import script.

The group by statement includes all columns in the table, excluding the primary key.

It will only delete one set of duplicate rows each time it's run, so if a row is repeated 4 times you will need to run this a minimum of 3 times. This is likely not as fast as John's solution, but works within an existing table. It also works when you don't have a unique id for each unique geometry (such as the osm_id in the original question).

I used a python script to repeat until duplicates were gone, and then ran a full vacuum. I think the script and vacuum each took about 30 minutes for a few hundred thousand duplicates from around 1.5 million records in 6 tables. Plenty good for a one-off. It went through the small tables very quickly.

```
DELETE FROM schema.table 
  WHERE primary_key IN
    (SELECT MAX(primary_key)
     FROM schema.table 
     GROUP BY ST_AsBinary(geom), col_1, col_2, col_etc
     HAVING COUNT(primary_key) > 1);
```

EDIT: modified SQL to avoid running multiple times based on @dbaston suggestion (below). I tried this query method on a large table (~1.5 million records, ~25,000 duplicate point rows), and after it ran for 45 minutes I canceled its execution. Running with the SQL above (using a smaller subquery from the HAVING COUNT) reduced each run to less than 30 seconds. After running 3 times, it was done with all duplicates. The SQL below should be OK for small tables.

```
DELETE FROM schema.table 
  WHERE primary_key NOT IN
    (SELECT MAX(primary_key)
     FROM schema.table 
     GROUP BY ST_AsBinary(geom), col_1, col_2, col_etc);
```

Comment: If you don't have a primary key, you can use the always available `ctid` column (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html)).

Comment: You can avoid running this multiple times by checking for `primary_key NOT IN (SELECT max(primary_key) ....`

Comment: @dbaston I made notes in the answer above. Removing the HAVING COUNT greatly increases the size of the subquery results, and therefore the number of comparisons the delete statement needs to make. I was surprised at how much longer execution was on a large table.

Comment: @NateWanner NOT EXISTS might give you some additional speed in this case.

Comment: @MichalZimmermann I'm not sure I follow you - both versions expect the subquery to return a result.

Comment: @NateWanner you said the query was slow -> using NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN should boost the performance.

Comment: @MichalZimmermann NOT EXISTS will return True if there is any result from the subquery, whereas IN will check if the value is in the list. In the queries above, I always have a result and am checking to see if a value is in the list. I can't think of a way to rewrite it that would not require regenerating the subquery for each row comparison, which would make it much slower. [EXISTS vs IN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24932/4062147)

Answer (score 1):

To make Miro's generic response a quite a bit faster you can use `ST_DWithin` which will only filter geometries with 0 distance between them using your spatial index (if you have added one).

```
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name a
USING schema_name.table_name b 
WHERE a.id > b.id 
AND ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom)
AND ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

@MAP answered to his own question:

> I finally found an easy way, which is working in my case:
>
> ```sql
> DELETE FROM planet_osm_point
>      WHERE ctid NOT IN (
>           SELECT max(ctid)
>           FROM planet_osm_point
>           GROUP BY osm_id
>       );
> ```
>
> found on this page:
> http://technobytz.com/most-useful-postgresql-commands.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on Miros and Timothy Daltons answers here is another improved answer:

```
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name a
USING schema_name.table_name b 
WHERE a.id > b.id 
AND ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom)
AND a.geom && b.geom;
```

The "[&&](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html)" is a spatial comparison for a intersection of 2D bounding boxes and thus lowers the query execution time (at least when a spatial index is existing).