# Removing duplicates geometry rows in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, sql

I am maintaining a table which has geometry datatype and it's possible that the table can contain duplicate geometries.
If I want to remove duplicate rows or select only non-duplicate one, will both the approach work same?

```sql
SELECT (ST_dump(ST_union(geom))).geom from mytable;
```

OR

```sql
DELETE FROM mytable a
USING mytable b 
WHERE a.id > b.id 
AND ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom)
AND a.geom && b.geom;

SELECT geom from mytable;
```

Will both the queries work same when we call `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Not sure how union behaves for duplicate geometries but the latter query is the correct way to do this. You can speed it up with a simple additional within condition https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/393163/6253

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Depends¹.

A flexible and generally better performing approach for both cases would be to use an `EXISTS` expression:

- `SELECT`:

  ```
  SELECT
    t.*
  FROM
    <mytable> AS t
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        <mytable> AS _t
      WHERE
        _t.id < t.id
        AND
        ST_Equals(_t.geom, t.geom)
    )
  ;
  ```
- `DELETE`:

  ```
  DELETE
  FROM
    <mytable> AS t
  WHERE
    EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        <mytable> AS _t
      WHERE
        _t.id < t.id
        AND
        ST_Equals(_t.geom, t.geom)
    )
  ;
  ```

*Note that `ST_Equals` makes use of a spatial index via [`~=`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Geometry_Same.html) - no need for additional conditions.*

The foremost advantage is avoiding an aggregation in the `SELECT`, leaving you with full access to rows themselves.

Both statements will keep the duplicate with the *lowest* `id`.

---

¹ As soon as there are **overlaps** between *non*-equal geometries, the `ST_Union` operation may have side-effects, and may return different geometric compositions.

More generally, being pedantically precise:

- the `ST_Union` of *equal* geometries may result in a different vertex order than a selection by `a.id > b.id`
- `ST_Union` *recreates* geometries, which may be subject to coordinate differences in the range of *floating point* imprecision

For `POINT` geometries this doesn't matter much. For other types, however, you will see a larger impact with higher geometric complexity - up to a point where you get (topo)logically deteriorated results.

Overall these consequences *may not be an issue for your use case*; yet, the `ST_Union` approach is not guaranteed to give you the same results as a simple `SELECT` by equality.